# GCP BigQuery loading data from a bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm really a freshman on the Google Cloud Platform. I'm trying to populate a BigQuery table with data pulled up from a bucket object CSV file. I created a Python test script to create and populate the table. The creation is done but when I run the file, I'm getting stuck.

My script:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import LoadJobConfig
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField

client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset('datasetname')


## Create the table

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('start_date', 'DATETIME', mode='NULLABLE'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('start_station_code', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('end_date', 'DATETIME', mode='NULLABLE'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('end_station_code', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('duration_sec', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('is_member', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE')
]
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('tablename')
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)  # API request

## Loading data


SCHEMA = [
    SchemaField('start_date', 'DATETIME', mode='NULLABLE'),
    SchemaField('start_station_code', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'),
    SchemaField('end_date', 'DATETIME', mode='NULLABLE'),
    SchemaField('end_station_code', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'),
    SchemaField('duration_sec', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'),
    SchemaField('is_member', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE')
]
#table_ref = client.dataset('dataset_name').table('table_name')

load_config = LoadJobConfig()
load_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
load_config.schema = SCHEMA
uri = 'gs://gcp-development/object.csv'

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    table_ref,
    job_config=load_config)

load_job.result()

destination_table = client.get_table(table_ref)
print('Loaded {} rows.'.format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Per the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#load-table-data-from-google-cloud-storage), that seems correct. However, I'm getting the following error I don't understand, and I don't know how to check out the logs to get more details.

error:

> `google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.`

**Where is the error stream?** I tried:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/queries/jobId
```

following the [troubleshooting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) but I retrieved nothing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible your CSV file is mis-formatted? Could you share an example of the file in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I could load data by using your script with no issues at all. You could check the full error message within the [Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) by selecting BigQuery in the first left menu. This may be related to a parsing error regarding the datetime fields. You could find more information about how to use the Logs Viewer in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#the_user_interfaces)

The data sample that I used was the following:

```
start_date,start_station_code,end_date,end_station_code,duration_sec,is_member
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,1,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,2,3,4
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,2,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,3,4,5
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,3,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,4,5,6
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,4,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,5,6,7
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,5,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,6,7,8
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,6,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,7,8,9
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,7,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,8,9,10
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,8,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,9,10,11
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,9,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,10,11,12
0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000,10,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999,11,12,13
```